# Is the formation of a zygote in fertilization an example of a mutex?

Tags: mutex

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygote):
Once the single sperm enters the oocyte, it completes the division of the second meiosis forming a haploid daughter with only 23 chromosomes, almost all of the cytoplasm, and the sperm in its own pronucleus.

I learnt a long time ago that when a zygote forms, no other sperm cells can enter new entity. 
Would this be an example of a mutex in nature?

Comment: Not really -- nature is probabalistic.  Most of the time it works out (only one sperm entrers), but sometimes it fails and the proto-zygote dies.

Comment: Also, how would you unlock the mutex?